# How do I express this first order differential in the form y = f(x)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $y=4$ and $x=2$ how can I express $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(13-2x)}{(2x-3)(x+1)}, x > 1.5$?

The partial fractions are (should be) $\frac{4}{(2x+3)} + \frac{3}{(x+1)}$ but when I go through my method I end up with the constant $c$ being $4.68$ etc... which seems strange. Maybe I am correct and just paranoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(13-2x)}{(2x-3)(x+1)}$$
$$\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{(13-2x)}{(2x-3)(x+1)}dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{(13-2x)}{(2x-3)(x+1)}dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{y} = [\frac{4}{(2x-3)}-\frac{3}{(x+1)}]dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{y} = [\frac{2d(2x-3)}{(2x-3)}-\frac{3d(x+1)}{(x+1)}]$$
$$\int \frac{dy}{y} =\int [\frac{2d(2x-3)}{(2x-3)}-\frac{3d(x+1)}{(x+1)}]$$
$$\\ln |y| = 2\ln|2x-3| - 3\ln|x+1| + c$$

When $y(2)=4$, we get $c=\ln 108$

Hope it helps now.

Comment: Yes! I just had the thought to do that myself and got 108, thank you very much for the help :)